# Reference a named Excel variable using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

Situation: I'm using Excel 10.  I have a named variable that uses a formula to compute it's value.  This is a named variable, not a named range (in the 'Name Manager' the name "MaxDate" refers to "=MAX(Sheet1!B:B)" where column B is a list of dates).  The computed value does not appear in any cells by itself, but rather is used in various formulas within the spreadsheet.

My problem:  How can I reference this named variable in VBA code?  Using range("MaxDate").value does not work.  I know I can simply put the value into a cell and reference the cell, but I'd like to find a way to reference the variable directly.  Any ideas?Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's some examples of working with your named variable:

```
Sub TestNamedVariable()

Dim varFormula As String
Dim varValue As Variant

'This will print the formula if you need it:
varFormula = ActiveWorkbook.Names("MaxDate")

'This will evaluate the named variable/formula
varValue = Application.Evaluate("MaxDate")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

For a given workbook with a Named variable "MyVar", valued "=MAX(Sheet1!B:B)".
Try the following code:

```
Evaluate(ActiveWorkbook.Names("MyVar").RefersTo)
```

Replace the ActiveWorkbook with the object you're referring if you need to.

Comment: OP stated they are not working with a named range - the name points to a formula (but not in any cell)

Comment: Agreed. Missed that it was in fact a formula. Code rewritten. @TimWilliams